# Image not taking up full width set on parent div

Tags: html, css

See this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kDdUC/2/)**

As you can see in the fiddle there is some empty space on left side of image. I have set the image to 100% width but its not taking all the space. You can check it by hover over it.

[image]

HTML

```
<ul class="ulteamlist">
    <li class="teamlist">
        <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/jpw2o7ofr/image.png">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        <p>Vikas Ghodke</p>
        <p class="tposition">Lead Developer</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.ulteamlist {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
li.teamlist {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px -1px #ccc;
    float: left;
    padding:0;
    display: block;
    width:40%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    position: relative;
}
li.teamlist:hover {
    background:#0dbca1;
}
li.teamlist:hover p {
    color:#fff;
}
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 210px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
li.teamlist:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
li.teamlist:nth-child(4n+4) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.no-js li.teamlist {
    display: block;
}
li.teamlist img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 210px;
    margin:0;
}
.teamlist p {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #5b5b5b;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
p.tposition {
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: -27px;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #9d9c9c;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: That's not a "gap" -- it's your PNG that has some transparent pixel in its left. http://jsfiddle.net/kDdUC/8/

Comment: @passerby Oh my god, how in the hell i missed it. Thanks its working now http://jsfiddle.net/kDdUC/7/ ,Can you make it as answer so i can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending from comments (both mine and OP's):

It's not a "gap", per say; it's some transparent pixel in the left of the original image:

[image: gap]

You can see it clearly in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kDdUC/8/):

```
<img src="http://s21.postimg.org/jpw2o7ofr/image.png" />
```

```css
body {
    background-color:yellow;
}
img {
    outline:1px solid black;
}
```

With placeholder picture your set up seems fine:

[image: placeholder]

http://jsfiddle.net/kDdUC/7/

Answer (score 0):

Just add this with your css..i tested it works

This is what you want rit..

```
.ulteamlist
{padding:0px;}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not asking about the white gap, i was asking about the green line which appears left on image, but now i got my answer, actually my image has 1px transparent side on left.

Answer (score -1):

Check Out By Changing the image as the image itself is having some space to its LHS.